# Php doesnt execute when coming from window.location

Tags: javascript, php, xampp

I have a php file named "savegame.php".

I use xampp. When i enter "localhost/morabaraba/savegame.php" as a url manually it works

i have a file "index.html" in the same folder as my "savegame.php" file and using window.location = "savegame.php" redirects
to c:\....\morabaraba\savegame.php but it does not echo back or update the database as the code in "savegame.php" says it should

```
   code in savegame.php
     <?php
              print 'i am working';
              //database updating details

      ?>
```

When i say enter localhost/morabaraba/savegame.php i mean typing it in the window, not coding it as window.location = "local/morabaraba/savegame.php" in the index.html file

Comment: Are you running the file using local server? if not than do it...

Comment: Loading a file off your hard-drive via a 'c:\' path does not pass it through a PHP interpreter.

Comment: What do you mean it directs to "c:\....\morabaraba\savegame.php"? You mean http://localhost/morabaraba/savegame.php, right?

Comment: shouldnt window.location pass it throught the PHP interpreter?

Comment: JAL it gives me this "file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/morabaraba/savegame.php".  i assume that means it just returns the file it doesnt run it? i am a newbie. How do i make it say "localhost/morabaraba/savegame.php"? i even tried to use ajax and it just said "no element found"

Comment: O K A Y finally it sank in, thank you Mr Alien and Mike Edwards. instead of clicking on the file to open it i should have typed in its localhost url...ohhhhh. Growing pains :) 30 minutes wasted eish